# How to identify end of file correctly

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I have to create a disassembler, read a `file.dump` and convert it to assembly.
I'm testing reading a txt file first. Here is my code:

```
 .data
INPUT_FILE:   .asciiz "C:\\Users\\myPath\\teste.txt"
BUFFER: .space 1024
ERROR_MSG: .asciiz "ERROR OPENING FILE :( "
.text
    # Open File
    li $v0, 13                  # Syscall for Open a File
    la $a0, INPUT_FILE          # Specify which file to open
    li $a1, 0                   # 0 = Read
    li $a2, 0
    syscall                    # Open the file (File Descriptor -> V0)

    blt $v0, $zero, Error_Opening_File      #Check if File was correctly opened
    move $s6, $v0               # Save the descriptor into s6  

read_file:
    # Read File
    li $v0, 14                 # Syscal for Read from file
    move $a0, $s6               # Pass the file descriptor to argument a0
    la $a1, BUFFER             # Address of Buffer to read
    la $a2, 4                  # Hardcoded Buffer size
    syscall

    blt $v0, $zero, Error_Opening_File


    # Write
    li $v0, 4       # Syscall for Print String
    la $a0, BUFFER
    syscall

    j read_file

    li $v0, 10
    syscall

Error_Opening_File:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, ERROR_MSG
    syscall
```

It's reading "correctly", but it never stops... When it reaches the last part of text, it just keeps repeating that last part.

Reading the documentation of `Syscall 14 (read from file)`

> $v0 contains number of characters read (0 if end-of-file, negative if error). See note below table

How may I make sure when it hits the end ?
How to make my code read piece by piece 'till there is nothing else to read?

Thinking that in the future I'll need to read an assembly code dumped into text-binary.

Comment: The answer is right there: the system call returns 0 in $v0 when end of file is reached.  So when that happens you should stop.

Comment: You already answered yourself: *"$v0 contains number of characters read (0 if end-of-file"*

Comment: So why it's never stopping if I'm already checking for it ?

Comment: I think you want `beq $v0, $zero, EOF_Input` after `blt $v0, $zero, Error_Opening_File`

Comment: @cschneid Ya. That worked like a charm ! Thank you.